# Boolean methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In order to ask something like:

```
MyClass::create().empty?
```

How would I set up `empty` within MyClass?

Empty (true/false) depends on whether a class variable `@arr` is empty or not.

Comment: Do you mean *class variable* `@@arr` or *instance variable* `@arr`?

Comment: In Ruby, there is `initialize` which is called by `MyClass.new`.

Comment: "In Ruby, there is initialize which is called by MyClass.new". Agreed. And it is good to follow that in Ruby; Stick to the yellow brick road when you have your Ruby slippers on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question mark is actually part of the method name, so you would do this:

```
class MyClass

  def empty?
    @arr.empty? # Implicitly returned.
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same as I showed in the last post, but with a different method name.

First, `create` must return something with an `empty?` method. For example:

```
class MyClass
  def self.create
    []
  end
end
```

If you want to be operating on instances of `MyClass` as per your last question:

```
class MyClass
  def self.create
    MyClass.new
  end

  def initialize
    @arr = []
  end

  def empty?
    @arr.empty?
  end

  def add x
    @arr << x
    self
  end
end
```

Here `MyClass` acts as a simple wrapper around an array, providing an `add` method.

```
pry(main)> MyClass.create.empty?
=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also need to check whether @arr is nil or not. This depends on your class definition of empty.

```
def empty?
  !@arr || @arr.empty?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Forwardable` to delegate `empty?` from your class to the array:

```
require "forwardable"
class MyClass
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@arr, :empty?

  def initialize(arr)
    @arr = arr
  end
end

my_object = MyClass.new([])
my_object.empty? # => true
```